# Slow console input when interactively plotting matplotlib

Tags: windows, performance, python-2.7, matplotlib, console

I want to input some stuff in the console and every now and then update a graph. Therefore I use the pylab interactive mode. However, when typing input the windows console responds with a short time delay as if too much memory is used by the interactive plotting.

Is there a way to avoid this slowing effect?

```
import pylab as plt
plt.ion() #░interactive mode on
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.draw()
while True:
    test=str(raw_input('Type something fast and observe the delay\n: '))
```

Comment: did you try to measure the delay with?

Comment: Not really, but it adds up if you type a lot fast. In that case it can take a few seconds for all the input to appear on the console. Within my spyder console I do not have the issue. Only in the windows console.

Comment: Ok. And you're sure that you don't have any delays when you don't plot anything?

Comment: Yes, if I delete the third and fourth line of code (so activating interactive mode but not plotting anything) the console responds quickly.